# dotPlant2 стандартная тема

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

Извиняюсь сразу если вопросы слишком простые, но в документации не нашел описания возникших проблем.

Если применить команду `$ ./yii admin/create-theme` генерируется папка theme в web. 
Отсюда у меня два вопроса:

1) Почему логика сайта помещается в папку web на которую я направляю apache. (Безопасно ли? И не было бы проще поместить папку как и вся логика в корень проекта? )

2) Как развертывать на хостинге ? (Почему `.gitignore` изначально не пропускает ее?) Когда проведешь deploy почему не во всех папках `.htaccess` (ну к примеру `module/config/web.php`)